# How to get a word bounded between `word' with regex? python

Tags: python, regex, string

Given the string

> (comparative of `good') changed for the better in health or fitness

I need to extract the first string bounded between the slanted single quote and the single quote

```
line = "(comparative of `good') changed for the better in health or fitness"
line.split("`")[1].split("'")[0]
```

I could have done the above but what is the regex solution to get the string bounded between the slanted single quote and the single quote

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import re
line = "(comparative of `good') changed for the better in health or fitness"
match = re.search(r"`(.*?)'", line)
print(match.group(1))
```

yields

```
good
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
import re

your_line = "(comparative of `good') changed for the better in health or fitness"
word = re.search(r"`([^']*)'", your_line).group(1)  # good
```

Comment: what's the difference between using `([^']*)` vs `(.*?)`

Comment: They will effectively match the same: `[^']*'` - anything, but `'`, followed by `'`, `(.*?)'` - minimal match containing anything with `'` at the end.

Comment: `\`(.*)'` - this, however, will match anything between `\`` and `'`, even if the matching line contains quotes.